# Mysql IF statement Error on Nested if sentence

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, mariadb

I am trying to create a procedure to update the `stopTime` field on my `works` table.
The query I am using is:

```
update  mydb.works  set stopTime= 
(IF((SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name = 'results_24') is NULL, 
(select stampTime from mydb.works where id = 24), 
(IFNULL((select stampTime from mydb.results_24 order by id desc limit 1),
(select stampTime from mydb.works where id = 24))))) where id=24;
```

Shortly, the query should get the related `results_` table `stampTime` as `stopTime` of `works` table's related entry.
If there is no table or empty table, the `stampTime` at the `works` table is used.

My problem occurs when there is no `results_` table I'm looking for. The statement should check if related `results_*` table exists and if not, it should get the `stampTime` from `works` table.

But it also executes the statement below (i.e: ELSE part)

```
IFNULL((select stampTime from mydb.results_24 order by id desc limit 1)
```

and I got the error (as expected)

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.results_24' doesn't exist
```

I checked the parenthesis and commas multiple times. I think there is no mistake about it.
What am I missing? It shouldn't execute the ELSE part, but it does. Why?

Thanks.

`OS: Raspbian`

`Mysql version: Mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv8l) using readline 5.2`

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like GMB alsready said you need some dynamic sql

```
SELECT IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name = 'results_24')
,@sql := 'update  mydb.works  set stopTime = IFNULL((select stampTime from mydb.results_24 order by id desc limit 1)
   ,(select stampTime from mydb.works where id = 24));'
   ,@sql := 'update  mydb.works  set stopTime = (select stampTime from mydb.works where id = 24);');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```